# Banner Slider doesn't show up .gif images

Tags: magento2, slider

I'm using [Banner Slider](https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2) on my magento 2.0.7, it works fine with .jpeg and .png , but if I try to load a .gif , it doesn't show it.

Comment: Is there any reference link that i can see.

Comment: I've just managed to do it , for some reason it wasn't uploading at all the .gif images , so I just uploaded them manually with the ftp , and added the url manually throught in the database